# Linq query no responde luego de actualizar Stored Procedure en EntityFramework

Tags: entity-framework, stored-procedure, entity-framework-6, linq-to-sql

Estoy trabajando con **EntityFramework 6**, tengo mi modelo creado (First DataBase) desde hace bastante tiempo. En mi proyecto tengo **algunas consultas con LINQ y otras** (para optimizar tiempos) realizadas con **Stored Procedures** (SP).

Ha funcionado correctamente hasta que necesité actualizar un SP existente. Para que mi modelo notara el cambio borré los 3 archivos que hacen relación al SP.

Luego sobre el modelo hago la actualización y obtengo los cambios del SP; hasta aquí todo normal. El inconveniente se produce cuando al ejecutar el sitio web, las consultas realizadas con LINQ no devuelven resultado alguno; aunque no tengan relación alguna con el SP ni tablas modificadas.

¿Cómo puedo solucionar este problema? No se producen excepciones durante la ejecución y si revierto los cambios en el modelo las queries con LINQ funcionan correctamente.

[image: Los archivos que eliminé del SP desde aquí para que el modelo reconociera el cambio en la DB]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finalmente resolví de la siguiente forma:

- Mantuve actualizado mi modelo con los cambios en el SP.
- Eliminé el SP desde la DB y provoqué el fallo llamando el SP desde el sitio web.
- Volví a crear el SP en la DB y tanto las queries con LINQ y el SP
  funcionaron correctamente.

Realmente no sé las razones por la cual dejó de funcionar ni porqué volvió a funcionar haciendo estos pasos...pero funcionó para mi!

Answer (score 1):

Seguramente hubo diferencias entre el molo guardado en VS con el real, recuerda actualizar ambas partes:

Desde el editor de Entity model de Vistual Studio:

1. "Update Model from Database" en cualquier parte en blanco del editor
2. Sobre nuestro "modelo.TT" pulsamos en "Run custom tool"
3. Sobre nuestro "modelo.context.TT" pulsamos en "Run custom tool"

Comment: Añadidas aclaraciones dentro @juankGlezz

Comment: Please be careful with linking to your own content on different sites, [you don't want to be a spammer](//es.stackoverflow.com/help/promotion). You should include the majority of the content here, use the link only as a reference, **and disclose your affiliation.**

Comment: El enlace contine capturas de pantalla más detalladas, pero lo quito